# How do you set a JLabel to take all the available width space?

Tags: java, html, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm trying to center the `JLabel` text and to change the background and foreground color. I tried to use HTML:

```
JLabel listHeader = new JLabel("<html><span style='background-color:#555;color:White;text-align:center;'>Tables</span></html>");
```

But it doesn't seem to work as you can see in the image below.

[Image of the components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwsDg.png)

[image]

The label is inside a panel that has the layout manager set to grid bag layout with the following constraints:

```
c.gridy=0;
c.gridx=0;
c.weighty=0;
c.weightx=1;
c.fill=GridBagConstraints.NONE;
c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
```

I tried with fill `BOTH` as well, same result.

How can I make the label take all the width space?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to anchor at the center, not on the start of the line.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to use HTML:

Don't use HTML.

> I'm trying to center the JLabel text

To center the text in the space available to the label you can use:

```
label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
```

> and to change the background and foreground color.

You need to make the label opaque:

```
label.setOpaque( true ):
label.setBackground( Color.RED );
```

> I tried with fill BOTH as well, same result.

Well, I don't think you want "BOTH" since you are only concerned with the width. You may also need to use the `weightx` constraint. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more information on using the constraints.

Without your `MCVE/SSCCE` we can't see exactly what you are doing.